# How to replace 'for' loop by 'xarray.apply_ufunc' to performing linear regression between "x" and "y" for a 11-day moving-window for a xr.Dataset?

Tags: python, python-xarray

Estimate the linear slope between 'x' and 'y' for each 11-day moving window by 1-day stride.

```py
from sklearn import linear_model
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr
import pandas as pd

# Create a dataset as an example
site = np.linspace(0,3,num=4,dtype='int8')
time= pd.date_range('2018-01-01','2020-12-31',freq='d')
x = np.random.randint(0,500,size=[len(site), len(time)])
y = np.random.randint(0,500,size=[len(site), len(time)])

_ds = xr.Dataset(data_vars=dict(
                    x=(["site", "time"], x),
                    y=(["site", "time"], y)),
                coords=dict(
                    site=site,
                    time=time))

# define the linear regression model
def ransac_fit(xi,yi, **ransac_kwargs):
    Xi = xi.reshape(-1, 1)
    yi = yi
    ransac = linear_model.RANSACRegressor(**ransac_kwargs)
    ransac.fit(Xi, yi)
    slope= ransac.estimator_.coef_
    b = ransac.estimator_.intercept_
    return slope, b
```

At present I am able to use 'for' loop for 'site' and 'time' to do that, which however is extremely clumsy...

```py
def clc_slope(_ds, window_size=11):
    slps    =[]
    bs      =[]
    mean_xs =[]
    mean_ys=[]
    
    var_x = _ds['x']
    var_y = _ds['y']
    
   # for loop for each year and date
    for year in np.unique(_ds.time.dt.year.values):
        for doy in np.unique(_ds.sel(time=str(year)).time.dt.dayofyear.values):
            
            # define inorg and endrg
            inorg = doy-np.int(window_size/2+1)
            enorg = doy+np.int(window_size/2)
            
            # calculate mean values of x and y for each moving window
            mean_x = np.nanmean(var_x.sel(time=str(year))[inorg:enorg].values)
            mean_y  = np.nanmean(var_y.sel(time=str(year))[inorg:enorg].values)
            
            mean_xs = np.append(mean_xs, mean_x)
            mean_ys  = np.append(mean_ys, mean_x)

            # start to estimate slope and intercept
            _x = var_x.sel(time=str(year))[inorg:enorg].values
            _y = var_y.sel(time=str(year))[inorg:enorg].values
            
            # if there is too many nans then assign slope and intcept to be nan
            if (np.isfinite(_x) & np.isfinite(_y)).sum()<((np.int(window_size/2)+2)*1):
                _slp=_b= np.nan
            else:
                try:
                    _slp, _b = ransac_fit(_x,_y, min_samples=0.6, stop_n_inliers=np.int(window_size/2)*1)
                except:
                    _slp=_b = np.nan

            slps = np.append(slps,_slp)
            bs   = np.append(bs, _b)

    outs = [slps, bs, mean_xs, mean_ys]
    return outs

# run the slope and intercept estimation for each site and concat afterwards
_dss = []
for st in ds.site.values:
    _ds = ds.sel(site=st)
    outs = clc_slope(_ds)
    _ds['slp']    = ('time',outs[0])
    _ds['b']      = ('time',outs[1])
    _ds['mean_xs']= ('time',outs[2])
    _ds['mean_ys']= ('time',outs[3])
    _dss.append(_ds)
dss = xr.concat(_dss, dim='site')
```

I know xarray.apply_ufunc can extremely save time, but I do not get this tricky approach. Would be supper appreciate if you can give a hint! Thank you!

Comment: sorry I'm having a bit of trouble tracking what exactly you're trying to do. do you want a regression of Y ~ X across all sites for each time period, where you have one regression per 11 day window (so ~3*365=1,195 regression results), or do you want one regression just of the 11 days for each site, so one result per (11 day window * site), so ~3*365*50=54,750 regression results?

Comment: Thanks for the response and sorry for the confusion, yes, the former, one regression per 11 day window (so ~3*365=1,195 regression results) for each year.

Comment: I saw your deleted question/answer below - just a tip - rather than `site = np.linspace(0,3,num=4,dtype='int8')` you could use `np.arange(4)` :) you could pass in dtype if you want as well, though as this is a coordinate, the difference is very small. usually it makes sense to focus on data types for data variables more than coordinates - you'd be literally saving 24 bytes with this optimization :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
rolled = ds.rolling(time=11, center=True).construct("window")

slps, bs = xr.apply_ufunc(
    ransac_fit,
    rolled['x'],
    rolled['y'],
    input_core_dims=[['window'],['window']],
    output_core_dims=[[],[]],
    vectorize=True,
    dask='parallelized',
)
```

This is the way that comes out by creating a 3rd dimension (**window**) using `rolling` function, then using `apply_ufunc` to broadcast dimensions of **site** and **time**.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't use `apply_ufunc`, but it does speed up the implementation quite a bit I expect.

xarray's rolling modules have a really powerful feature called [`construct`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.core.rolling.DataArrayRolling.construct.html). What it does is to take a rolling window, and rather than reducing it, expand it into a new dimension. xarray does this without ever copying data - it just provides one slice into the array for each element along the rolled dimension, with each slice being the length of the window, and offset by one from the previous slice:

```py
In [3]: rolled = _ds.rolling(time=11).construct("window")

In [4]: rolled
Out[4]:
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (site: 50, time: 1096, window: 11)
Coordinates:
  * site     (site) int8 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ... 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2018-01-01 2018-01-02 ... 2020-12-31
Dimensions without coordinates: window
Data variables:
    x        (site, time, window) float64 nan nan nan nan ... 350.0 9.0 303.0
    y        (site, time, window) float64 nan nan nan nan ... 246.0 351.0 310.0
```

You can use this to perform arbitrary operations along each window. It's also really helpful for prototyping complex windowed operations, because you can see exactly what's going on in each slice.

Next, for each slice, we can stack the `site` and `window` dimension, to get all the observations you'd like for each regression in one vector:

```py
In [5]: stacked = rolled.stack(obs=("window", "site"))

In [6]: stacked
Out[6]:
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (time: 1096, obs: 550)
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2018-01-01 2018-01-02 ... 2020-12-31
  * obs      (obs) MultiIndex
  - window   (obs) int64 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ... 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10
  - site     (obs) int64 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3
Data variables:
    x        (time, obs) float64 nan nan nan nan nan ... 81.0 136.0 194.0 303.0
    y        (time, obs) float64 nan nan nan nan nan ... 470.0 300.0 329.0 310.0
```

Now that we have this, we can wrap your regression function so it accepts and returns a Dataset. I'll add a new dimension `coeff` because `slope` is a vector (you could alternatively just grab the scalar `slope` with `slope.item()` and skip the extra dim):

```py
def ransac_fit_xr(ds, **ransac_kwargs):
    xi, yi = ds.x.values.ravel(), ds.y.values.ravel()
    mask = (~np.isnan(xi))
    # you could apply your masking rule here if you'd like:
    # if mask.sum() < len(mask) / 2:
    #     return xr.Dataset({"slope": (("coeff", ), [np.nan]), "b": np.nan})
    xi, yi = xi[mask], yi[mask]
    slope, b = ransac_fit(xi, yi, **ransac_kwargs)
    return xr.Dataset({"slope": (("coeff", ), slope), "b": b})
```

Now, we can loop over the elements of `time` to build our regression results:

```py
In [22]: results = []
    ...: for i in stacked.time.values:
    ...:     results.append(ransac_fit_xr(stacked.sel(time=i, drop=True)))
    ...: res_ds = xr.concat(results, dim=stacked.time)

In [23]: res_ds
Out[23]:
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (time: 1096, coeff: 1)
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2018-01-01 2018-01-02 ... 2020-12-31
Dimensions without coordinates: coeff
Data variables:
    slope    (time, coeff) float64 -0.1954 0.3 -0.0878 ... -0.1385 0.05444
    b        (time) float64 413.6 303.5 366.0 271.4 ... 342.1 256.4 362.8 303.
```

This runs reasonably quickly. A persistent challenge I have with sklearn's estimators is there is no good way to run tensor regressions, where you want to pass in an array of arguments, run the regression along some subset of the dimensions, and then receive an array of outputs. xarray's [`polyfit`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.polyfit.html) does do this, but you currently can only run polynomial regressions. So if you have something more complex like your `RANSACRegressor`, you have to accept the performance hit of an outer loop. You could speed this up by parallelizing it with [`map_blocks`](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.array.map_blocks.html) if you'd like.

Comment: Thanks for the promising suggestion.
I just noticed that I made a mistake when creating the site dimension, there should be only 4 unique values in that dimension. I just updated the original post.
I tried your code and indeed it is much faster. But i lost the site dimension in the end. I am afraid that I did not clearly describe my question: **the resulting slope and b have same dimension as x and y**.
I have to use RANSAC regression because the outliers are really annoying in my case... What should I do to keep that dimension? any further suggestions? Thanks very much

Comment: I have an idea of keeping using `apply_ufunc` after applying `construct`:
`xr.apply_ufunc(ransac_fit,rolled['x'],rolled['y'], input_core_dims=[['site'],['time']],output_core_dims=[['site'],['time']], vectorize=True, dask='parallelized')`
But come out new challenge... you may have some ideas...

Comment: Got it. Yeah so it seems that you did want one regression result per time*site after all? In that case, the same method will work, but don’t stack window and site. And then you’d have to loop over both time and site. And yeah at that point it may be worth figuring out how to set up map_blocks or apply _ufunc

Comment: I finally figured it out!

`rolled = ds.rolling(time=11,center=True).construct("window");

_x, _y = rolled['x'] , rolled['y'];

slps, bs = xr.apply_ufunc(ransac_fit,_x,_y,input_core_dims=[['window'],['window']],output_core_dims=[[],[]], vectorize=True, dask='parallelized')`
I test for several times, it is a little faster than using for loop. Thank your for the inspiration!

Comment: nice! glad you got it :) feel free to [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) if you'd like!

Comment: Yeah just added it. Thank you Michael.